# Add Custom Meta Tag on Delphi Intraweb

Tags: delphi, intraweb

I need to set a custom meta tag to the Intraweb Component.

If I set the meta on the Template (HTML), this meta came after a lot of content (Custom Intraweb Meta and Self generated JavaScript) and is useless. As you know, `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />`must be the first meta tag of a page.

Need help on this.

I'm using Rad Studio 2007.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got the solution.

Just add this line to the form "On Create"

`ExtraHeader.Add('<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"> ');`